# Почему не запускается скрипт?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему скрипт может не запускаться? Ошибок в консоли нет. Все скрипты у меня обвёрнуты в

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

и все они работают, кроме одного, но повторюсь, ошибок в консоли нет. Пытался обвернуть его отдельно в

```
$(window).load(function(){

});
```

результата это не дало. Если я выполню скрипт в самой консоли, то скрипт отработает как положено. Скрипт загружается полностью.

Comment: Как Вы узнали, что скрипт не работает?

Comment: На странице не произошли изменения, которые происходят если я пропишу скрипт в консоли.

Answer (score 0):

*Дорогие учёные. У меня который год в подполе происходит подземный стук. Объясните, пожалуйста, как он происходит.*

---

Когда Вы запускаете скрипт в консоли, страница не такая, как когда скрипт выполняется в `$(document).ready(`.

Comment: Так я же запускаю скрипт после создания DOM всей страницы, она должна быть такая же.

Comment: @SLideR11 Ну тогда скрипт должен работать. Зачем Вы спорите с очевидным? Так как показывать Ваш скрипт Вы не хотите (вероятно, это секретный скрипт), Вам придется удовлетвориться таким ответом.